# Can I upload files to a certain website to see exactly what code they contain and what they do (heuristics)?

Tags: file-system, uefi

I want to upload files somewhere to see exactly what their behaviour is, but I’m not sure how. One of them is an EFI file. Does anyone know some website or method, like on a virtual machine, to check what they do?

Comment: You can use Virustotal to find out if they may be malicious, but you can never be 100% sure

Comment: Try reverse engineering to see exactly what a file does

Answer (score 2):

As to the EFI application, you may be able to run and analyze it in a virtualized UEFI environment using [QEMU with OVMF](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/OVMF). I'm not sure if there are online services which support OVMF, but if you're able to set up a sufficiently restricted VM (no network access, no shared folders, no access to devices), you could do this locally.

Otherwise, reverse engineering as suggested by UndercoverDog will probably be your only option.